# In Angular, what ways can you auto-update a data binding that is bound to a method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

Say you have an object with a method:

```
/*
chat.author    ==  a String
chat.message   ==  a String
chat.timestamp ==  a Date 
chat.timeago() ==  a method that returns a string, like "2 minutes ago"
*/
```

And your html looks something like:

```
<div>{{ chat.author    }}</div>
<div>{{ chat.message   }}</div>
<div>{{ chat.timeago() }}</div>
```

The return value of chat.timeago() will change based on the elapsed time since chat.timestamp, so it may change from "just now", to "a few seconds ago", to "a minute ago", "2 hours ago", etc.

What options exist to instruct Angular when to update the data that is bound to the method, and which option is the most elegant or traditional way in Angular?

Comment: I would suggest using a directive to represent timeago and just use specific intervals and draw it manually on the ui with native DOM operation like `innerHTML` or even with jqlite .text/.html. If you use $timeout, $interval(very bad) it will run the digest cycle again and all the watchers as well... Just to update timeago it is an overkill especially when your app gets larger. With angular you need to reply on digest cycle to update bindings and you end up doing a timeout etc... which has its own disadvantages.

Comment: @PSL Good point here. A directive would be a harder but nicer way to achieve this.

Comment: @Okazari yeah but it will be definitely worth, but would n't be harder to implement. Saw during the last ng-conf there was a presentation where this was discussed, even for mouseover/mouseout effects dont use ng-* events instead just bind events manually. On a larger ui or (when it gets larger) you will end up having serious performance issues. So just invoke a digest cycle only when it is really worth..

Comment: @PSL In general i'm not for using custom directives. It almost always do something you could do with angular built-it services/directives or it is just no what directives are intended for. As far as i know directives are intended to add a behaviour to some component. Here is exactly a good use case for a nice custom directive. <div update-time>0</div> of things like that. Have you got a link about theses informations ? I'm very interested in it.

Comment: @Okazari you can youtube ng-conf-2015 there are many videos from different speakers. And yes something like that and just keeping it simple and traditional way to manipulate DOM (just a small part of DOM it is afterall and a small bit of logic to show updated time)

Comment: @PSL I love this way of thinking. It really fit angular's one.  Thanks for the informations i will watch this asap.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind to variable form scope and update this variable using the [`$timeout` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

Angular can refresh view state only when some conditions occurred (callback executed, AJAX received, $scope updated, ...), so you can't bind to function and expect that it refresh automatically

Answer (score 1):

The way you've done it is perfectly acceptable.

Binding to a method is no different than binding to a variable.  Whenever the digest cycle runs, it evaluates each binding as though it was an expression, and angular provides a lot of support for more complex expressions (ternary expressions, mathematical operators, et al).

As an aside, there is no advantage to putting the expression inside a `$watch`, as there is an implicit watch formed by your binding.

Edit:  If you want the value to update as time progresses, then use the `$timeout`/`$interval` service, as others have suggested.

Comment: I worked in a project with a lot of performance issue with angular. We discovered that binding a method got a higher cost than binding a var. At each digest it will run the entire function instead of just doing a comparison between the previous value and the new value. It would be better to bind a variable and update it depending on our need.

Comment: @Okazari I understand your concern -- the same problem comes up when you are using filters.  Though I'm slightly surprised that your findings would show much of a difference.  I would love to see a jsperf on this.

Comment: The team broke almost all the web standards (asked by the client) and did some ugly things. We worked a lot to find where all theses trouble were coming from. It was a lot of things, including this one. Only littles things, but a LOT (Between 2000 and 6000 binding on the page). Hall of shame was binded functions and $watch uses.

Comment: Good to know.  We use the closure compiler, which will eliminate the extra function call if the body of the function is simple.  So in all cases, we work towards readability.  I'm going to bring this up to the Angular team and see what they say, but I do recognize what you are saying, and it's a good gotcha to know about.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this should look like this :

```
<div>{{ chat.author    }}</div>
<div>{{ chat.message   }}</div>
<div>{{ chat.timeago.time   }}{{chat.timeageo.message}}</div>
```

**In your Controller :**

```
 $scope.chat = {
    author: "Me",
    message: "Hi!",
    timeago: {
         time: 0,
         message: "seconds ago"
    }
 }
```

Now in your controller you'll probably use the [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service to update your "timeago" message

```
var updateTimeago = function(){
    $scope.timeageo += 10;
};
$interval.(updateTimeago(), 10000);
```

Every ten second your message will update.

Modify this to do your exact needs. Hope it helped.

EDIT : As PSL suggested, it would be great to use a custom directive to update the timer instead of using $interval that can be bit greedy in term of performance.